# Rats! WebGL hit a snag

Tags: discussion, advertising, google-chrome

> Rats! WebGL hit a snag.

[image]

It is the first time I have this error. It just appeared **once** on Stack Overflow while browsing with:

- Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) + HTTPS Everywhere
- macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 (16G29)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)

Memory usage perfectly normal: only Chrome is open and only on friendly websites.

Stack Overflow configuration:

- Disable stickiness
- Reduce Ads
- Currently displayed ad was for Microsoft Azure in Japanese.
- Allowed applications: Stack Overflow Careers and Winter Bash

[edit]
Two weeks later, happened again on the same Japanese ad for Microsoft Azure:
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, we (SO) don't use WebGL. Might be an ad (and if it is - it shouldn't be using WebGL either).

Comment: I'll add that I can't seem to repro. Sure this isn't an extension/add-on?

Comment: I only have HTTPS Everywhere. And issue doesn't happen anymore. My guess was a temporary advertising issue?

Comment: No idea, but likely culprit.

Comment: If it is caused by an Ad it could explain [this one as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356620/is-stack-overflow-webrtc-on-chrome-macos-preventing-computer-sleep) maybe.

Comment: Get a Jack Russell.

Comment: @rene webgl and webrtc are not related, if it is really the same source, then there should really be an audit, I wonder what else they are doing... ps: webgl is a good way to uniquely identify devices.

Comment: Maybe it's just Chrome's unhelpful way of telling you that you need to close some tabs!

Comment: This occasionally happens on my dev machine if I browse documents through office365.

Comment: [Modernizer](https://modernizr.com/) is a very popular library that can use WebGL

Comment: Not really webgl, but some fingerprinting is done through 2D context by https://cdn.doubleverify.com/dvbs_src_internal34.js which serves some ads in here. I wouldn't be surprised that some other tracking systems gone through the filters (if any).

Comment: @gman to do what? (except testing for webgl support, but even then, according [to this](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1892), they don't even create a webgl context for webgl detection, I doubt they would for something else...)

Comment: It might have to do with your ISP or government.

Comment: The other post (that @rene points to) also mentions having 25 tabs open. Koinkidink?

Comment: Could WebGL be running in the background under any other (from the many) opened tabs?

Comment: -1 for not having your tabs spell out something

Comment: @Will Direct that -1 to Chrome that does not allow any plugins to manage the tabs, like breaking them up into several rows.

Comment: @juagicre nope, this error message is thrown on the increminated tab.

Comment: @Cœur How many opened tabs does it takes to navigate on internet ??????

Comment: What's your question? This is just Chrome's way of telling you the WebGL process crashed unexpectedly. There is no "user serviceable" solution to this issue.

Comment: @Oded it happened again today, on the same advertising for Microsoft Azure in Japanese.

Comment: I've alerted our ads team - someone there will investigate.

Comment: @Oded I got this today, FYI.

Comment: @Oded I'm thinking this exception is related: `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…5 2.92V4.31l-7.2z"` B @ clc.min.js?v=96bc0285e9e9:1

Answer (score 2):

I have hit this issue a few times in recent days. To get around it on Chrome, enable "Disable WebGL" in chrome://flags.

Comment: Not a very useful solution, given the increasing (warranted) use of WebGL.

Comment: This is why I said, "to get around it." I'm not yet aware of a solution to the glitch, just this--which is obviously a workaround because I'm sure some people may actually need WebGL to be active in their situations. I'd love to hear a true solution to the problem! It just seems (and this is only my opinion) that it's a bug that only the developers of the Chrome web browser or those who maintain the WebGL API (the Khronos Group) might be able to truly resolve. In the meantime, at least you can get around the problem!

Comment: Another good solution along the same lines is to uninstall your web browser and disable power to your computer. No more WebGL errors!

Comment: @nathanchere Thanks, that solved my problem!

Comment: @nathanchere Why the hyperbole? This answer describers a useful workaround. If it is indeed an ad using WebGL, you wouldn't be missing out on anything. Sure, some people might need WebGL but I'd wager most don't.

Comment: I find the reaction to this answer to be insane, 7 downvotes for someone trying to be helpful.