# Microsoft advert appears to break image upload?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, image-upload

This has happened a few times for me over the past week or so but this now it seems to be happening consistently:

### Ms Advert:

[image]

### No MS advert:

[image]

Doesn't seem to affect meta.

- No console errors
- can't see anything getting blocked, etc in the network tab
- Disabled all extensions
- Recreated in incognito mode.

Browser is Chrome 61.0.3163.100.

I've tried clearing the cache, etc.

Though the question is similar to [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357411/cant-upload-image-anymore) I don't believe this is my virus software that's causing this issue. I have only seen this issue when being server the Microsoft ad ([see answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357884/542251)). With different ad (different SE sites, etc.) the image upload works.

Comment: That file size error shows up when you open the modal?

Comment: Yes, that's how it looks when I open it. Error and all

Comment: As Tanner mentioned: Any extensions?

Comment: I've just disabled all extension, same issue. Also checked in incognito mode, and same issue.

Comment: Nope I'm getting it on **questions**. The [one I'm testing is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765483/create-asp-net-rdlc-two-columns), no answers on it.

Comment: Maybe same as these? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357591 | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357411

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't upload image anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357411/cant-upload-image-anymore)

Comment: I *think* it's related to ads in the sidebar, see my answer.

Comment: @liam was able to fix that post as proof once the ad was not present.

Comment: I do appreciate the dupe @Cerbrus, the answer though, I'm not using McAffee, I have bit defender, work computer so I can't disable it. I think Taner might have it. It works on other SE sites (which doesn't have this advert). I can't find a question where that isn't served to prove yet

Comment: **Blame Microsoft**, see my latest update to answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus i agree this is not to do with McAfee, so not a duplicate of that post. See my answer.

Comment: Then it's still a duplicate, but the answer on the other one is just incorrect.

Comment: @Cerbrus i think this one should stay open though and the other closed, as this has more details now and a possible cause.

Comment: Whatev's guys. Let me know and I'll close if appropriate, that answer is wrong though (in this case)

Comment: Repro'd on Android Chrome. Definitely not McAfee, Norton, or any other antivirus.

Comment: FWIW, just got it with a non-Microsoft ad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0vlh.jpg. (It's Android Chrome on the desktop site, which is why the scrim is off.)

Comment: @Tanner Could it be related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356651/rats-webgl-hit-a-snag which is apparently also caused by MS ads?

Comment: @balpha what was the issue/fix? will you be writing up an answer?

Comment: @Tanner Just posted. As you can see, it took a while to write it up :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fixed now. This was a fun one. Long story short: It wasn't Microsoft's fault, it was ours. If you're curious about the dirty details, here goes:

The ad is loaded in a IFRAME. The ad provider needs to communicate between the main page and the IFRAME, which means cross-origin communication. Since IE8 we've had the `postMessage` API to do that sort of thing, but that's a little too modern apparently.

So instead, in order to perform this communication, it's using a well-known hack ([example](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/)) that uses [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) to talk between the IFRAME and the parent. It looks like this is used to send some blob of HTML over to the IFRAME; either way, the IFRAME's `window.name` contains a long string of stuff.

Once the IFRAME is done with whatever it needs to do, it's being a nice citizen and cleans up after itself, by setting its `window.name` back to the empty string. So far so good.

[And now for something completely different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGK8IC-bGnU). The image upload popup is loaded via a little JavaScript helper in our code called `asyncLoad`. This helper has an option called `callback`, documented like this:

```
callback: An additional explicit callback, used only as fallback if the '.async-load'
          element has no 'data-after-load' attribute. Can be null/undefined.
```

In the case of the image uploader, this parameter is *not* null or undefined; rather, it's the callback that actually initializes the dialog (adds functionality, hides stuff that shouldn't be visible, etc.)

Now, as that piece of documentation says, the `asyncLoad` helper first checks for the `data-after-load` attribute, and it parses it as a period-separated lookup. Here's the relevant code:

```
var func = $this.data('after-load') || '';

if (!func && !options.callback) {
    return;
}

// after-load callbacks will usually be like "StackExchange.container.publicMethod"
// so need to get a reference at each level, e.g.
// window["StackExchange"]["container"]["publicMethod"]
var levels = func.split('.'),
    toCall;

// callback should be accessable from window
for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    toCall = (toCall || window)[levels[i]];
}

toCall = toCall || options.callback;
if (typeof toCall === 'function') {
    toCall($this);
}
```

So it splits `"StackExchange.container.publicMethod"` into `["StackExchange", "container", "publicMethod"]`. Then it looks up `window["StackExchange"]`, on the result of that it looks up `["container"]`, etc.

Now what happens in the case of our image upload popup, where the `callback` parameter is provided but the `data-after-load` attribute isn't?

In that case, `func` is an empty string, thus `func.split(".")` is a single-element array `[""]`. So the `for` loop executes a single time:

```
toCall = (toCall || window)[levels[i]];
```

translates to

```
toCall = (toCall || window)[""];
```

translates to

```
toCall = window[""];
```

Hmm. That doesn't exactly look intentional, but fortunately it works anyways. Because there isn't actually a property with the empty name on the global object, `toCall` is `undefined`, and thus after

```
toCall = toCall || options.callback;
```

`toCall` is actually our option-provided callback.

So while this sort of only works by accident, it works.

Well, it *worked*. Until this ad came along. Rember how I said that it cleaned up after itself by erasing the IFRAME's `window.name`?

Let me quote from the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) that defines named access on the `window` object, emphasis mine:

> Let childBrowsingContexts be all document-tree child browsing contexts of activeDocument's browsing context **whose browsing context name is not the empty string**, in order, and including only the first document-tree child browsing context with a given name if multiple document-tree child browsing contexts have the same one.

It turns out that Chrome ignores the part I've bolded. And thus because the IFRAME set its `window.name` to the empty string, the main page's `window[""]` is now the IFRAME (or rather, its `WindowProxy`).

Which is why `toCall = window[""];` no longer is `undefined`, and doesn't get replaced by the `callback` parameter, thus the `callback` is never called, and therefore the image uploader popup is not initialized.

And because there's a `typeof` check, we never attempt to execute `toCall` (which is why you didn't see an exception in the console).

So... that's it.

Here's the whole fix for this issue:

[image: screenshot of a diff that causes levels to be the empty array if func is empty]

As I said, this was fun.

Comment: Deep... So was it just that Ad or were other ads from the same provider causing the issue too? That was the only one I was able to repro the issue on consistently, the MS bit was just a joke. Or is it simply because I was seeing that ad most based on the tags I frequent.

Comment: I don't know, it may have been more than this one. We also recently transitioned to a new ad provider. So this might eventually have become more frequent.

Comment: @Tanner - I've seen others ads reported as causing the same problem.

Comment: Good work guys, I always think the more inconsequential the fix the more difficult it is to figure out the problem.

Comment: As an aside @balpha did you know the link in your profile throws an error? http://unicornify.appspot.com/ *Python 2.5 is no longer available*

Comment: Apologies to Microsoft. *This time*.

Answer (score 8):

I've found what ***could be*** a consistent cause. I was testing with answering a question and inserting an image:

Fails with a **Microsoft** ad in the sidebar bar:

[image]

Refresh a page enough times until you don't see an ad in the sidebar and it seems to work. Reproduced in this scenario a few times now.

[image]

If you load a [non-Microsoft tagged post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765145/docker-ubuntu-environment-variables) to get a different ad, it also seems to work fine:

[image]

### **So Blame Microsoft**

NOTE: I have Ghostery running, but it was disabled for these tests.

Comment: I also have that advert. Not sure if that proves the theory or not.

Comment: Managed to get a page with a **different advert**, works. I think you've got it

Comment: Good sleuthing dude.

Comment: Tanner ad this as an answer to the other and I'll close as a duplicate

Comment: @Liam we can just close that as a dupe of this, as there is more details here. I've already voted on the other post and pinged Oded.

Comment: What question are you getting that ad on? I can't even get is to display on an [tag:asp.net] question.

Comment: @Cerbrus Try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765483/create-asp-net-rdlc-two-columns. I get it consistently. It's hard for me to find a question without an MS advert but I work in C# so maybe being targeted.

Comment: @Cerbrus try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765145/docker-ubuntu-environment-variables

Comment: Same pattern of ads, no MS ad, so kinda hard to check if it's reproducible (for me) :-/

Comment: Yeah, see I don't get an MS advert there. I'm guessing it depends on the advert targeting algorithm. even in incognito I struggle to find a question that doesn't serve that advert

Comment: See mainly MS ads under posts on [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), although i'm struggling at the moment to get one. The algorithm must think i've been shown enough MS ads today with the amount of refreshing I've done :-)